# =IMPORTXML Not importing what is expected

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import the Sector and Industry tags into a google doc.

I am using...

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABT/profile?p=ABT","//span[@data-reactid='21']")
```

Shows in three different cells:

```
Profile
Healthcare
About Our Ads
```

But all I want is Healthcare in one cell

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABT/profile?p=ABT","//span[@data-reactid='25']")
```

Shows in three different cells:

```
Financials 
Medical Devices 
Sitemap
```

But all I want is Medical Devices in one cell

What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting two other `span`s as well - thus three rows instead of one.

You might want to use a more precise xpath, like those:

```
=IMPORTXML(
  "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABT/profile?p=ABT",
    "//p/span[text()='Sector']/following-sibling::span[1]/text()")

=IMPORTXML(
  "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABT/profile?p=ABT",
    "//p/span[text()='Industry']/following-sibling::span[1]/text()")
```

[image]